# Load multi-line JSON data into HIVE table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have a JSON data which is a multi-line JSON. I have created a hive table to load that data into it. I have another JSON which is a single-line JSON record. When I load the single-line JSON record to its hive table and try to query, it works fine. But when I load the multi-line JSON into its hive table, it gives below exception:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeExcep‌​tion: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@8b89b3a; line: 1, column: 0]) at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@8b89b3a; line: 1, column: 3]
```

Below is my JSON data:

```
{
  "uploadTimeStamp" : "1486631318873",
  "PDID" : "123",
  "data" : [ {
    "Data" : {
      "unit" : "rpm",
      "value" : "0"
    },
    "EventID" : "E1",
    "PDID" : "123",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "Timezone" : 330,
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "pii" : { }
  }, {
    "Data" : {
      "heading" : "N",
      "loc3" : "false",
      "loc" : "14.022425",
      "loc1" : "78.760587",
      "loc4" : "false",
      "speed" : "10"
    },
    "EventID" : "E2",
    "PDID" : "123",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "Timezone" : 330,
    "Version" : "1.1",
    "pii" : { }
  }, {
    "Data" : {
      "x" : "1.1",
      "y" : "1.2",
      "z" : "2.2"
    },
    "EventID" : "E3",
    "PDID" : "123",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "Timezone" : 330,
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "pii" : { }
  }, {
    "EventID" : "E4",
    "Data" : {
      "value" : "50",
      "unit" : "percentage"
    },
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "PDID" : "123",
    "Timezone" : 330
  }, {
    "Data" : {
      "unit" : "kmph",
      "value" : "70"
    },
    "EventID" : "E5",
    "PDID" : "123",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "Timezone" : 330,
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "pii" : { }
  } ]
}
```

I am using /hive/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar

Below is my create table statement:

```
create table test7(
uploadtime bigint,
pdid string,
data array<
struct<Data:struct<
unit:string,
value:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>,
struct<Data:struct<
heading:string,
Location:string,
latitude:bigint,
longitude:bigint,
Location2:string,
speed:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>,
struct<Data:struct<
unit:string,
value:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>,
struct<Data:struct<
x:int,
y:int,
z:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>,
struct<Data:struct<
heading:string,
loc3:string,
latitude:bigint,
longitude:bigint,
loc4:string,
speed:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>
>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
'/xyz/abc/';
```

Edit:

Adding the single line JSON and new table create stmt with error:

```
{"uploadTimeStamp":"1487183800905","PDID":"123","data":[{"Data":{"unit":"rpm","value":"0"},"EventID":"event1","PDID":"123","Timestamp":1487183800905,"Timezone":330,"Version":"1.0","pii":{}},{"Data":{"heading":"N","loc1":"false","latitude":"16.032425","longitude":"80.770587","loc2":"false","speed":"10"},"EventID":"event2","PDID":"123","Timestamp":1487183800905,"Timezone":330,"Version":"1.1","pii":{}},{"Data":{"x":"1.1","y":"1.2","z":"2.2"},"event3":"AccelerometerInfo","PDID":"123","Timestamp":1487183800905,"Timezone":330,"Version":"1.0","pii":{}},{"EventID":"event4","Data":{"value":"50","unit":"percentage"},"Version":"1.0","Timestamp":1487183800905,"PDID":"123","Timezone":330},{"Data":{"unit":"kmph","value":"70"},"EventID":"event5","PDID":"123","Timestamp":1487183800905,"Timezone":330,"Version":"1.0","pii":{}}]}
```

---

```
create table test1(
uploadTimeStamp string,
PDID string,
data array<struct<
Data:struct<unit:string,value:int>,
EventID:string,
PDID:string,
TimeS:bigint,
Timezone:int,
Version:float,
pii:struct<>>,
struct<
Data:struct<heading:string,loc1:string,latitude:double,longitude:double,loc2:string,speed:int>,
EventID:string,
PDID:string,
TimeS:bigint,
Timezone:int,
Version:float,
pii:struct<>>,
struct<
Data:struct<x:float,y:float,z:float>,
EventID:string,
PDID:string,
TimeS:bigint,
Timezone:int,
Version:float,
pii:struct<>>,
struct<
EventID:string,
Data:struct<value:int,unit:percentage>,
Version:float,
TimeS:bigint,
PDID:string,
Timezone:int>,
struct<
Data:struct<unit:string,value:int>,
EventID:string,
PDID:string,
TimeS:bigint,
Timezone:int,
Version:float,
pii:struct<>>
>
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
```

### '/ABC/XYZ/';

```
MismatchedTokenException(320!=313)
...
...
...
FAILED: ParseException line 11:10 mismatched input '<>' expecting < near 'struct' in struct type
```

Comment: It seems multi-line JSON is not supported and you'll have to flat the document to a single line in order to use the JSON SERDE.

Comment: I converted the multi line json to a single line json now. Now, when I create the table and load the data, all the value i get while selecting is null .

Comment: It means that the table definition does not match the data structure. I'll take a look later on.

Comment: Edited question with latest single line JSON, new create table statement and latest error

Comment: This JSON is a mess. You have an array that contains elements with different structures.

Comment: Yes, but this is what I have to load. I can't change the structure. How to process this very JSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data

```
{"uploadTimeStamp":"1486631318873","PDID":"123","data":[{"Data":{"unit":"rpm","value":"0"},"EventID":"E1","PDID":"123","Timestamp":1486631318873,"Timezone":330,"Version":"1.0","pii":{}},{"Data":{"heading":"N","loc3":"false","loc":"14.022425","loc1":"78.760587","loc4":"false","speed":"10"},"EventID":"E2","PDID":"123","Timestamp":1486631318873,"Timezone":330,"Version":"1.1","pii":{}},{"Data":{"x":"1.1","y":"1.2","z":"2.2"},"EventID":"E3","PDID":"123","Timestamp":1486631318873,"Timezone":330,"Version":"1.0","pii":{}},{"EventID":"E4","Data":{"value":"50","unit":"percentage"},"Version":"1.0","Timestamp":1486631318873,"PDID":"123","Timezone":330},{"Data":{"unit":"kmph","value":"70"},"EventID":"E5","PDID":"123","Timestamp":1486631318873,"Timezone":330,"Version":"1.0","pii":{}}]}
```

---

```
add jar /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core.jar
```

---

```
create external table myjson
(
    uploadTimeStamp string
   ,PDID            string

   ,data            array
                    <
                        struct
                        <
                            Data:struct
                            <
                                unit:string
                               ,value:string
                               ,heading:string
                               ,loc3:string
                               ,loc:string
                               ,loc1:string
                               ,loc4:string
                               ,speed:string
                               ,x:string
                               ,y:string
                               ,z:string
                            >
                           ,EventID:string
                           ,PDID:string
                           ,`Timestamp`:bigint
                           ,Timezone:smallint
                           ,Version:string
                           ,pii:struct<dummy:string>
                        >
                    >
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
stored as textfile
location '/tmp/myjson'
;
```

---

```
select * from myjson
;
```

---

```
+------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| myjson.uploadtimestamp | myjson.pdid |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         myjson.data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          1486631318873 |         123 | [{"data":{"unit":"rpm","value":"0","heading":null,"loc3":null,"loc":null,"loc1":null,"loc4":null,"speed":null,"x":null,"y":null,"z":null},"eventid":"E1","pdid":"123","timestamp":1486631318873,"timezone":330,"version":"1.0","pii":{"dummy":null}},{"data":{"unit":null,"value":null,"heading":"N","loc3":"false","loc":"14.022425","loc1":"78.760587","loc4":"false","speed":"10","x":null,"y":null,"z":null},"eventid":"E2","pdid":"123","timestamp":1486631318873,"timezone":330,"version":"1.1","pii":{"dummy":null}},{"data":{"unit":null,"value":null,"heading":null,"loc3":null,"loc":null,"loc1":null,"loc4":null,"speed":null,"x":"1.1","y":"1.2","z":"2.2"},"eventid":"E3","pdid":"123","timestamp":1486631318873,"timezone":330,"version":"1.0","pii":{"dummy":null}},{"data":{"unit":"percentage","value":"50","heading":null,"loc3":null,"loc":null,"loc1":null,"loc4":null,"speed":null,"x":null,"y":null,"z":null},"eventid":"E4","pdid":"123","timestamp":1486631318873,"timezone":330,"version":"1.0","pii":null},{"data":{"unit":"kmph","value":"70","heading":null,"loc3":null,"loc":null,"loc1":null,"loc4":null,"speed":null,"x":null,"y":null,"z":null},"eventid":"E5","pdid":"123","timestamp":1486631318873,"timezone":330,"version":"1.0","pii":{"dummy":null}}] |
+------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
select  j.uploadTimeStamp
       ,j.PDID

       ,d.val.EventID
       ,d.val.PDID
       ,d.val.`Timestamp`
       ,d.val.Timezone
       ,d.val.Version

       ,d.val.Data.unit
       ,d.val.Data.value
       ,d.val.Data.heading
       ,d.val.Data.loc3
       ,d.val.Data.loc
       ,d.val.Data.loc1
       ,d.val.Data.loc4
       ,d.val.Data.speed
       ,d.val.Data.x
       ,d.val.Data.y
       ,d.val.Data.z

from    myjson  j
        lateral view  explode (data) d as val
;
```

---

```
+-------------------+--------+---------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+------+------+------+
| j.uploadtimestamp | j.pdid | eventid | pdid |   timestamp   | timezone | version |    unit    | value | heading | loc3  |    loc    |   loc1    | loc4  | speed |  x   |  y   |  z   |
+-------------------+--------+---------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+------+------+------+
|     1486631318873 |    123 | E1      |  123 | 1486631318873 |      330 | 1.0     | rpm        | 0     | NULL    | NULL  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|     1486631318873 |    123 | E2      |  123 | 1486631318873 |      330 | 1.1     | NULL       | NULL  | N       | false | 14.022425 | 78.760587 | false | 10    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|     1486631318873 |    123 | E3      |  123 | 1486631318873 |      330 | 1.0     | NULL       | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL  | NULL  | 1.1  | 1.2  | 2.2  |
|     1486631318873 |    123 | E4      |  123 | 1486631318873 |      330 | 1.0     | percentage | 50    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|     1486631318873 |    123 | E5      |  123 | 1486631318873 |      330 | 1.0     | kmph       | 70    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+-------------------+--------+---------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks Dudu for this. But when I created table with same JSON and same create statement, I get uploadTimeStamp and PDID as NULL. A few more columns are coming as NULL.

Comment: hive> select * from myjson1;
OK
NULL    NULL    [{"data":{"unit":"rpm", "value":"0","heading":null,"loc3":null,................................................

Comment: On my other 1900 JSONs following similar structures also, the first two columns of uploadtimestamp and pdid is giving null.

Comment: As you can see, this is a tested code.  Please check your real data vs your example data.

Comment: Are you using the multi-line JSON with timestamp 1486631318873 posted initially by me or you have converted the same into single line JSON? When I tried with multiline JSON, it gave me "Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@432a6a69; line: 1, column: 2]" on select * from myjson;

Comment: And when i convert the same multi line to single line, it gives NULL for uploadtimestamp and PDID. I am not able to figure out, why is it not working for me.

Comment: The only change which I am doing as compared to your create table statement is, changing timestamp to times. Because using timestamp is giving me "FAILED: ParseException line 26:28 Failed to recognize predicate 'Timestamp'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in column specification" but seems it does come to you. I am ADDING "hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar" for JsonSerde. "ADD JAR /hive/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar;"What could be the reason for this difference?

Comment: I'm away from a computer until tomorrow. Columns' names cannot be changed because the columns are being populated according to the match between their names to the json keys. For the demo I used the original json which I flatted to a single line

Comment: My concern is not the column names. I just can't figure out why same create table statement is not giving me same o/p as yours which is expected one . I tried using single line and multi line. Single line giving null for uploadtimestamp and pdid and multiline giving IOException during select *

Comment: **1)** Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.7.0 **2)** add jar /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core.jar

Comment: This is bizzare now. I am using same input file as yours to test. When I do select with lateral view same as yours, all the values except for j.uploadtimestamp,j.pdid,d.val.pdid and d.val.TimeS are coming same as yours. But these four are coming as NULL.

Comment: i downloaded hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.jar. Earlier I was using hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar as JsonSerde. After using version 1.2.1, atleast the uploadtimestamp and pdid are coming as actual values now. The only problem now left is d.val.TimeS which is still coming as NULL. When I create table with timestamp as column name, it throws error as "FAILED: ParseException line 26:28 Failed to recognize predicate 'Timestamp'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in column specification".  Timestamp is an identifier in HIve. So instead, I change timestamp to times. And it throws NULL on select

Comment: Please try to quote the name with grave accent -  \`Timestamp`

Comment: I am not able to proceed if I convert the uploadTimeStamp and timestamp to bigint instead of string. I want to use the from_unixtime functions but uploadTimeStamp being string type, it does not allow. If I change data type of uploadTimeStamp and timestamp to bigint instead of string, then it gives below error"

Comment: hive> alter table ABC CHANGE uploadtimestamp uploadtimestamp bigint;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. The following columns have types incompatible with the existing columns in their respective positions :
uploadtimestamp
hive>

Comment: Please open a new post for this with relevant example

Comment: Done:-----     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644561/unable-to-work-with-unixtimestamp-column-type-in-string-data-type

Comment: I answered the new question but also updated this accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Was having the same issue, then decided to create a custom input format which can extract the multiline(pretty print) json records.

This JsonRecordReader can read a multiline JSON record in Hive. It is extracting the record based on balancing of curly braces - { and }. So the content between first '{' to the balanced last '}' is considered as one complete record. Below is the code snippet:

```
public static class JsonRecordReader implements RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {

    public static final String START_TAG_KEY = "jsoninput.start";
    public static final String END_TAG_KEY = "jsoninput.end";

    private byte[] startTag = "{".getBytes();
    private byte[] endTag = "}".getBytes();
    private long start;
    private long end;
    private FSDataInputStream fsin;
    private final DataOutputBuffer buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();

    public JsonRecordReader(FileSplit split, JobConf jobConf) throws IOException {
        // uncomment the below lines if you need to get the configuration
        // from JobConf:
        // startTag = jobConf.get(START_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
        // endTag = jobConf.get(END_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");

        // open the file and seek to the start of the split:
        start = split.getStart();
        end = start + split.getLength();
        Path file = split.getPath();
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(jobConf);
        fsin = fs.open(split.getPath());
        fsin.seek(start);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next(LongWritable key, Text value) throws IOException {
        if (fsin.getPos() < end) {
            AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
            if (readUntilMatch(false, count)) {
                try {
                    buffer.write(startTag);
                    if (readUntilMatch(true, count)) {
                        key.set(fsin.getPos());
                        // create json record from buffer:
                        String jsonRecord = new String(buffer.getData(), 0, buffer.getLength());
                        value.set(jsonRecord);
                        return true;
                    }
                } finally {
                    buffer.reset();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable createKey() {
        return new LongWritable();
    }

    @Override
    public Text createValue() {
        return new Text();
    }

    @Override
    public long getPos() throws IOException {
        return fsin.getPos();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        fsin.close();
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        return ((fsin.getPos() - start) / (float) (end - start));
    }

    private boolean readUntilMatch(boolean withinBlock, AtomicInteger count) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            int b = fsin.read();
            // end of file:
            if (b == -1)
                return false;

            // save to buffer:
            if (withinBlock)
                buffer.write(b);

            // check if we're matching start/end tag:
            if (b == startTag[0]) {
                count.incrementAndGet();
                if (!withinBlock) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (b == endTag[0]) {
                count.getAndDecrement();
                if (count.get() == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // see if we've passed the stop point:
            if (!withinBlock && count.get() == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end)
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

This input format can be used along with the JSON Serde supplied by hive to read the multiline JSON file.

```
CREATE TABLE books (id string, bookname string, properties struct<subscription:string, unit:string>) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'JsonInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

The working code with samples is here: https://github.com/unayakdev/hive-json

Comment: Please add some code here and don't only add a link. A link can get outdated over time.